# É possível criar um botão no Visual C# através de uma linha de comando?

Tags: c#

Boa tarde a todos.
Gostaria de criar botões apartir linha de comandos no Visual C#. Isso é possível?

Minha ideia final é criar uma espécie de planilha com 10x10 botões (total 100 botões). Fazer 1 por 1 na interface daria muito trabalho na hora de criar ou alterar propriedades